# rails 3.1 routing issue

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, routes, hyperlink, ruby-on-rails-3.1

When I am viewing the page in my web browser (this is across multiple browsers), my navigation bar is repeating the route path in parentheses next to the alias for the link. (i.e. it shows About(/about)). Here is the code I am using for my navigation bar

```
  <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "Contact", contact_path %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li> 

match '/contact', :to => 'pages#contact'
match '/about',   :to => 'pages#about'
match '/help',    :to => 'pages#help'

root :to => 'pages#home'
```

I have checked the rails api and this syntax seems correct. The links themselves are working fine. I have restarted the server and this is an issue that persists across multiple browsers. My test suite passes completely. I can't seem to figure out why this issue is persisting.

edit: This also doesn't appear anywhere in the page source either, so I have no clue how it is even showing up.
Ok this gets even weirder it seems like this persists for outbound links that are coded in general html. If I try to code

```
 <a href="www.example.com>example</a>
```

It will look like "example www.example.com". This looks like a more general linking issue.

Comment: I would check your front end code (HTML/CSS/JS). There are two reasons I say this: 1) it's happening for links that aren't created with Rails helpers and 2) it's happening in multiple browsers. That sort of implies that it's not Rails.

Comment: I have found the bug, and I think it is rails related. In order to track it down I recreated the project from scratch to see if I could reproduce it. It turns out that when I tried to include compass in my rails 3.1 project it created a directory called stylesheets in my public directory. I deleted it thinking it wouldn't change anything. However when I recreated the project from scratch, this issue didn't pop up until I added a stylesheets directory in the public directory, to see if that was it. It turns out that even if you delete it, links will not work properly and html will be valid.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware that you were using an asset gem. It'd make sense (somewhat) that a bug with one of those could cause this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was due to a bug in the compass gem, see my comment above for full details.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [naming them](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes):

```
match '/contact', :to => 'pages#contact', :as => "contact"
match '/about',   :to => 'pages#about', :as => "about"
match '/help',    :to => 'pages#help', :as => "help"
```

If that doesn't help, look at your routes with `rake routes` and see if that can point you in the right direction.

Edit:

You could try:

```
link_to "Contact", :controller => "pages", :action => "contact"
```

Just as a sort of sanity check.

Comment: I just named all of them as you have suggested and that did not work. I then tried rake routes and it gave me contact  /contact(.:format) {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"contact"}
       about  /about(.:format)   {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"about"}
   help  /help(.:format)    {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"help"}
   root  /                  {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"home"}

Comment: This (link_to "Contact", :controller => "pages", :action => "contact") did not solve the problem either.

Comment: Are you modifying the link_to helper anywhere?

Comment: Well, there's really no reason for that to happen. Are you able/willing to put your entire project up on github?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3431/discussion-between-evan-cordell-and-demondeac11)